# why does perl's Module::Load::Conditional::check_install find uninstalled module?

Tags: perl

--> perl -v
This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 0 (v5.24.0) built for x86_64-linux

I'm trying to conditionally load a perl module if it's installed using...

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
use Module::Load::Conditional qw[can_load check_install requires];                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

if(check_install( module => 'dvm_common')) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    use dvm_common;
    print "Looks like dvm_common is installed, so it was loaded.\n";
} else {
    print "Looks like dvm_common is not installed.\n";
}

exit;
```

Won't compile, complains about missing module...

```
--> perl -c ./mod_load_cond_test.pl
Can't locate dvm_common.pm in @INC (you may need to install the dvm_common module) (@INC contains: etc...  .) at ./mod_load_cond_test.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./mod_load_cond_test.pl line 6.
```

I thought the whole point of using this was to test for the existence of the module before loading it ?

Comment: Can you solve your problem using this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2864617

Comment: Is this as easy as changing "use" to "require" ?  Seems to work.

Answer (score 3):

`use` is a compile-time statement, so the interpreter will load a module immediately when it it passing through the source and encounters a `use` statement, as if you had written

```
 BEGIN { require Module; Module->import }
```

To load a module at run-time, you can use `require`

```
if(check_install( module => 'dvm_common')) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    require dvm_common;
    dvm_common->can("import") && dvm_common->import;   # optional
    ...
```

or string `eval`:

```
if(check_install( module => 'dvm_common')) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    eval "use dvm_common;1" or die $@;
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to call import at run time. `my $dvm_avail; BEGIN { $dvm_avail = check_install( module => 'dvm_common'); } use if $dvm_avail, 'dmv_common';`